# HTML- Select box on focus highlight border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to highlight the border of the select box/div when that box is in use to select an item

Here's the code on hTML side

```
  <div class="styled-1">                   
      <select>
          <option value="1">OPTION - 1</option>
          <option value="2">OPTION -2 </option>
          <option value="3">OPTION - 3</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.styled-1 select {
    width: 312px;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    border: none;
    left: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #8F4A11;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

What is the way pout to define a CSS of the type below for ".styled-1" above?

```
textarea:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #719ECE;
}
```

I tried the below but no luck

```
.styled-1:focus {
        outline: none !important;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #719ECE;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:focus` works on the `select` element; so, you can style the `select` element like this:

```
.styled-1 select:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #719ECE;    
}
```

Here's a JSfiddle showing the results: http://jsfiddle.net/n83p5qz7/

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$('select').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).parent('div').css('border-style','solid');
    }).blur(
    function(){
        $(this).parent('div').css('border-style','dashed');
    });
```

You can have a look on the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs1juyvL/)

Comment: [`focus-within`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/) can handle this without any JavaScript now.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are passing the `:focus` pseudo-selector to the `div` instead of the element inside the `select` you want to target.
Try something like this:

```
.styled-1 > select option:focus {
                 border: 1px solid 'your preferred color here'
                 box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #719ECE;
```

}

**Edit**:
Seems that I misunderstood your objective. This works but not to what you want to achieve.